# how to copy a file with button

Tags: android, file

i know how to copy paste afile but with one button that make acopy and paste .

```
static void copyFile(String readFile,String writeFile ){

    try {
        FileInputStream fi = null;
        FileOutputStream fo = null;

        try {
            fi = new FileInputStream(readFile);
            fo = new FileOutputStream(writeFile);

            //Read File

            byte[] byt = new byte[fi.available()];
            int r =0;
            while((r=fi.read(byt))!=-1){

                //fo.write(byt);
                fo.write(byt, 0, r);
            }
            fi.close();
            fo.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    finally{

    }
```

but  how to copy by one button and paste with another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call method which copy file from source to path within your `onClickEvent` of your <kbd>Button</kbd>.

onClickEvent Handler  snippet :

```
 Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click   
                copy(filesrcpath, filedestpath); // Pass Filesrc and FilePath
            }
        });
```

---

`Copy()` snippet which takes two parameter one source and another destination path.

```
public void copy(File src, File dst) throws IOException 
{
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);

// Transfer bytes from in to out
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int len;
while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) 
   {
    out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
in.close();
out.close();
}
```